# C# - Mascara de CPF

Tags: c#, textbox, aplicação-desktop, mask, placeholder

Estou querendo colocar um efeito de placeholder numa caixa de texto de mascara.

A ideia é ativar a máscara de CPF assim que entrar na caixa de texto e desativá-la se a caixa de texto estiver vazia quando sair.

```
private void mskCpf_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mskCpf.Text = "";
        mskCpf.Mask = "999\.999\.999-99";
    }
```

Neste código ele não reconhece a contrabarra e por isso não funciona desta forma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método contrário do [`Enter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?view=netframework-4.7.2) é o [`Leave`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=netframework-4.7.2). O Leave é atirado quando o controle perde o foco, já o Enter, é atirado quando um controle ganha foco.

Você pode associar isso com este evento, sem precisar criar um método dedicado apenas para exibir ou ocultar a máscara:

```
maskedTextBox1.Enter += (object enterSender, EventArgs enterArgs) => { maskedTextBox1.Mask = @"999\.999\.999-99"; };
maskedTextBox1.Leave += (object leaveSender, EventArgs leaveArgs) => { maskedTextBox1.Mask = ""; };
```

Adicione essas duas linhas na inicialização do Form e estará tudo pronto.